# Xamarin Forms deploying to new device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Ok so I have an Alcatel TCL 9001X (cheap phone, but should still do the job)

This phone is not rooted - straight from the shop.
I start a new project in Xamarin Forms all up to date

[image: Xamarin - 6.1.5]

And now when I run the project I get this error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task ResolveLibraryProjectImports: Could not load file or assembly 'libZipSharp, Version=1.0.6195.19505, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. (TCL_9001X_002.Droid)

I have no idea why it won't just run.
Android version is 6.0.1 and I have selected that as my target version as well.

Any ideas on how to get it running?
App runs fine on an iOS device.

Comment: Does it work in an emulator?

Comment: I use the genymotion simulator and no it doesnt

Comment: Is the libZipSharp library added as a reference for your Android project?

Comment: No not yet - I'll look into that. Just weird it's a default project and you to reference something right away??

Comment: Seems to be this error, but it should be fixed in the most current version of Xamarin https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44667

Comment: So turns out that was the correct answer. I got my macOS drive formatted to being Case-Sensitive and that includes mysterious system files on new projects :-)

Comment: maybe you will find xamarin.forms package in application manager, try to delete it

Comment: Ok cool I added it as an answer so that you can mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running into this error with case sensitivity https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44667